# Lightning Component in Visualforce Page - issues with navigateToSObject

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, navigation, salesforce-classic

I have a lightning component hosted in Visualforce page.
Lightning Experience is not enabled and it is still Salesforce Classic.
I have records displayed in data table.
When record name is clicked I want to navigate to record detail page.

Below is my code

COMPONENT

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="CurrentItem" type="Company__c" /> 

    <tr>                  

       <td data-label="Name">
           <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!v.CurrentItem.Name}"><a href="" onclick = "{!c.navigateToRecordPage}">{!v.CurrentItem.Name}</a></div>
       </td>



       <td data-label="City">
           <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!v.CurrentItem.City__c}">{!v.CurrentItem.City__c}</div>
       </td>                      
       <td data-label="State">
           <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!v.CurrentItem.State__c}">{!v.CurrentItem.State__c}</div>
       </td>                        
    </tr>

</aura:component>
```

CLIENT JS CONTROLLER

```
({
    navigateToRecordPage: function(component, event, helper) {

        //var parentrec = component.get("v.CurrentItem");
        //sforce.one.navigateToSObject(parentrec.Id);


        //but it throws error when component is in VF page and lightning experience // is not enabled, it is still salesforce classic                

        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        var parentrec = component.get("v.CurrentItem");
        console.log(parentrec.Id);        
        navEvt.setParams({
        "recordId": parentrec.Id        
        });
        navEvt.fire();

    }

})
```

Below are various options I used to do navigation to record detail page but I am receiving error for all of them.

OPTION 1

> Using force:navigateToSObject -  ERROR -  Action Failed  [Cannot read
>   property 'setParams' of undefined] Failing descriptor:

OPTION 2

> Using sforce.one.navigateToSObject  -   ERROR Action Failed [sforce is
>   not defined] Failing descriptor

OPTION 3

> hardcoding link in href attribute like "/objectid" EXCEPTION -
>   receiving SAME ORIGIN EXception

I have similar code using force:navigateToSObject  working correctly in another org which has Lightning Experience enabled.
I assume these issues could be related to Salesforce Classic and related to the containers.

Any idea how I can get around this without switching on Lightning Experience ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So below is the resolution to this issue, I was receiving below error,
Refused to display 'https://xxxx.my.salesforce.com/xxxxxx' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'
I had "Development Mode" switched on. After switching it off, I was able to navigate without any errors.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using plain old JavaScript for classic like

```
window.location.assign=url here
```

may want to detect whether you are inside Lightning container or classic and based on that for classic use simple window navigation

Comment: Mohith, Could you please clarify ? Is this not going to be SAME ORIGIN issue ?

Comment: It's not going to give you same origin as you are redirecting browser window to new url .Have you tried it ?

Comment: I changed the code as below but still seeing the same origin error
  ({
 navigateToRecordPage : function(component, event, helper) {
   
        var parentrec = component.get("v.CurrentItem");
        
     
        window.location.href= "/" + parentrec.Id;

 }

})

Comment: Are you using Lightning out on vf?

Comment: Yes,  I have Outer component in VF page. Outer component uses another inner component. Code snippet given in the question is inner component's code.  Click event is for inner component

Comment: Also, in my app I only have , <aura:dependency resource="c:outerComponent"/> 
Do I have to add dependancy for innercomponent as well ?

Comment: I am guessing it might because you do not have my domain enabled .Need to research further here .Also kindly note that just enabling Lightning experience won't put your users in Lightning experience .So what's stopping you from just enabling a lightning experience without making user a lightning experience user?

Comment: I do have mydomain enabled.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/02/lightning-components-visualforce-lightning.html

Comment: Can you try window.location.assign instead ?Check the blog above

Comment: Mohith,, below is what I did,
 removed my inner component, added test link to outer component to  navigate to hardcoded record id. used window.location.assign with hardcoded record id, But still receiving SAMEORIGIN error

Comment: What happens if you move to different org where just Lightning experience is enabled? Also is locker switched on ? Can you disable it to see if that's culprit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50640/discussion-between-mohith-shrivastava-and-apn).

Comment: the same code works without any error in different org which has lightning experience enabled
and the EXACT SAME code doesn't work in org which is classic and don't have experience enabled.  so, I enabled lightning experience and made myself lightning experience user in the original org but I still see the same error

Comment: I switched off development mode and everything worked fine. Thanks for all the help!